# Counting clusters in a hashset in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures, hashset

I'm making a hashset ADT in c for a homework assignment. I cannot figure out for the life of me why my logic isn't working for a function that counts clusters in a hashset.

```
 void printClusterStats (hashset_ref hashset) {
   int **clusters = (int**)calloc (hashset->length, sizeof(int));
   assert (clusters);
   int ct = 0;
   // i traverses hashset->array
   // ct adds up words in each cluster
   // this loop screws up vvv
   for ( int i = 0; i < hashset->length; ++i) {
      if (hashset->array[i] == NULL) {
         clusters[ct] += 1;
         ct = 0;
      }else {
        ct += 1; 
      }
   }
   clusters[ct] +=1;  //catch an ending cluster

   printf("%10d words in the hash set\n", hashset->load);
   printf("%10d length of the hash array\n", hashset->length);
   for ( int i = 0; i < hashset->length; i++){
      if (clusters[i] == 0) continue;
      else{
         printf("%10d clusters of size %3d\n", clusters[i], i);
      }
   }
   free(clusters);
}
```

The output of this function looks like:

```
        26 words in the hash set
        63 length of the hash array
        96 clusters of size   0
        32 clusters of size   1
        16 clusters of size   2
         4 clusters of size   4
         4 clusters of size   6
       305 clusters of size  33
-703256008 clusters of size  34
-703256008 clusters of size  35
```

For my input hashset, there are 26 words in an array 63 long. However the counting screws up somehow.

EDIT: I've counted the clusters manually and discovered every count is 4 times what it should be. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line creates an array of pointers to int

```
int **clusters = (int**)calloc (hashset->length, sizeof(int));
```

rather than an array of int that you actually want if you are storing cluster counts

```
int *clusters = (int*)calloc (hashset->length, sizeof(int));
```

Consequently, when you do `clusters[ct] += 1;` it will be treated as pointer arithmetic, and add 4 to the cluster count each time, since you are on a system with 4-byte pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
int **clusters = (int**)calloc (hashset->length, sizeof(int));
```

Should be

```
int *clusters = (int*)calloc (hashset->length, sizeof(int));
```

I'm not very competent at c yet, so I can't explain why this solved my problem. But there you go if you were curious!

Here's the correct output

```
26 words in the hash set
63 length of the hash array
24 clusters of size   0
 8 clusters of size   1
 4 clusters of size   2
 1 clusters of size   4
 1 clusters of size   6
```